# K^2-Partitioning method for web graph

Tags: graph-databases

I am working on your paper "Practical Representations for Web and Social Graphs" as a part of my research seminar and I have been facing some difficulties in understanding of K^2-Partitioning method.

Could it be possible for anyone to explain it with some diagrams of the web graph and how to do this partitioning of the graph? If you have some rough sketch of any small example, then could you please share that with me? I really want to understand it.

I have already created a small example of google as a web graph and want to apply this K^2-partitioning method but I am not able to do apply it.

Below is the link for the paper.

https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2063747

I have already searched for many things related to this but have not found anything. Moreover, I have contacted the authors of these papers so that they might have some examples related to this method but did not get any reply yet.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.